# filter not working in python (json output)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, filter

I'm trying to filter a json output in python, but not working. Here is my json output

```
[ 
        {
            "type": 1
            "name" : "name 1",
            "field" : "aaa",
        }, 
        {
            "type": 2
            "name" : "name 2",
            "field" : "bbb",
        }, 
        {
            "type": 1
            "name" : "name 3"
            "field" : "ccc"
        }, 
]
```

What I would like to see:

```
[ 
        {
            "field" : "aaa",
        }, 
        {
            "field" : "bbb"
        }, 
        {
            "field" : "ccc"
        }, 
]
```

Here is my code, but it isn't working. May someone help and show me what am I doing wrong or missing? I'm getting error 500 when I try to load /test in my browser.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test')
def Test():
  uri = "https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/projects/"
  params = {"search":"my_test"}

# Get my_test data from URI
  response = requests.get(uri, params=params)

# Transform json input to python objects
  input_dict = json.loads(response)

# Filter python objects with list comprehensions
  output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if x['field']]

# Transform python object back into json
  output_json = json.dumps(output_dict)

# Show json on browser
  print (output_json)
```

Comment: Please, give us a `response` sample

Comment: `input_dict = json.loads(response)` is wrong for two reasons.  First, `response` is a custom object class, but json expects a string, so you would want to use `json.loads(response.body)` instead.  Second, requests is awesome, so they gave you a shortcut to do this -- just use `response.json()`.

Comment: Also, you're _printing_ the result, but shouldn't you be _returning_ it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

I tried the suggestions, but it didn't work. I keep getting the error message below:

```
2020-01-16T10:37:33.440-03:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
2020-01-16T10:37:33.440-03:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray,
```

'

Fortunately, I could solve this issue with the code below:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test')
def Test():
  uri = "https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/projects/"
  params = {"search":"my_test"}

  response = requests.get(uri, params=params).content
  data = json.loads(response)
  paragraph = "id: " + str(data[0]["id"]) + "; Description: " + data[0]["description"] + "; path: " + data[0]["path"]
  return({"Test" : paragraph})
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
input = [ 
    {
        "type": 1,
        "name" : "name 1",
        "field" : "aaa"
    }, 
    {
        "type": 2,
        "name" : "name 2",
        "field" : "bbb"
    }, 
    {
        "type": 1,
        "name" : "name 3",
        "field" : "ccc"
    }
]
```

this:

```
output = [x['field'] for x in input]
```

return this:

```
[u'aaa', u'bbb', u'ccc']
```

if you want a list of dicts instead:

```
output = [{'field': x['field']} for x in input]
```

Comment: He wants a list of dicts, not a list of strings.  How about `[{'field': x['field']} for x in input]` instead?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks John, added.